# How to query multiple linked record to return one row in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables like this:

```
Product table                        Identity table


Product | Role  | id                  id | Flag
--------+-------+----                 ---+-----
A       | Phone | 1                    1 |  Y
A       | iPad  | 2                    2 |  Y
A       | PC    | 3                    3 |  N
```

I want to query this table in such a way that I get following result (All products where flag is Y):

```
Product | Role1  | Role2 
--------+--------+-------------
A       | Phone  | iPad
```

Please suggest how this can be done.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Which type of SQL is this? If it's Microsoft, you pay be able to use PIVOT to get what you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for up to two roles:

```
select p.product,
       min(role) as role_1,
       (case when max(role) <> min(role) then max(role) end) as role_2
from product p join
     identity i
     on p.Id = i.Id and i.flag = 'Y'
group by p.product;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SELECT Product,
 MAX(CASE WHEN Role='Phone' THEN value END) as Role1,
 MAX(CASE WHEN Role='IPad' THEN value END) as Role2,
 MAX(CASE WHEN Role='PC' THEN value END) as Role3
FROM Product
JOIN Identity ON Product.Id = Identity.Id AND Identity.Flag = 'Y'
GROUP BY Product
```

You can add as many roles as you need to the select list